# Passing integer to a function that has enum as input parameter

Tags: c, enums, capl

I've got a question

What shall happen if we have the following :

```
typedef enum  {s1=0,s2,s3} states ;

void test( states x ) ;
```

when using the function test , what happens if I use it like the following :

```
test(6);
```

Shall it be mapped to the nearest enum value , or it needs to be handled in the function implementation ?

Comment: What language ? Please tag appropriately. Note that this would give you a compile-time error in most sensible languages.

Comment: Sorry , forgot to write it , I want to know this in CAPL as well as C

Answer (score 2):

enum are effectively treated as int by most C compilers.  They are just syntactic sugar to make code more readable.  In your case, 6 will be passed to the function and the function has to handle it.

Answer (score 1):

[for C]

If doing

```
test(6);
```

`6` will be passed to `test()` (as `enum`s are (treated as) `int`s) and it shall be trapped by the function's input validation.

---

**Update:**

Input validation is not done automagically. It needs to be coded explicitly.

Comment: Sorry , Sounds I did not get you correctly , does that mean a compilation error , or I should handle all of the cases in the function implementation ?

Comment: @MohammedAbdelhamid: Please see the update to my answer.